# Java: Get rid of a Character followed by a 1 or 2 Digit Number (0-15) using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, replace, expression

I want to get rid of all sequences of a character followed a digit (0-15) from some Strings.

I'm not very into Regex, I tried my best but didnt came up with a solution to this problem.

For the number sequence, i used: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

The character which indicates the sequence i use an "@"

The following replacements need to be done:

- @12Test --> Test (@12 replaced)
- @0Test --> Test (@0 replaced)
- @16Test --> @16Test (@16 not replaced, only 0-15)

I've created the following JUnit Testcases in order to test the regular expression:

```
public class ReplacementTests {
@Test
public void testNoReplacement1() {
    String actual = "Should nothing happen with this String";
    String expected = "Should nothing happen with this String";
    actual = appendRegexReplacement(actual);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
public void testNoReplacement2() {
    String actual = "12Should 5nothing 16happen2 with this13 String";
    String expected = "12Should 5nothing 16happen2 with this13 String";
    actual = appendRegexReplacement(actual);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
public void testReplacement() {
    String actual = "@12There @144are @5some @16which i @15want to @0get rid of!";
    String expected = "There @144are some @16which i want to get rid of!";
    actual = appendRegexReplacement(actual);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

private String appendRegexReplacement(String replacement) {
    String regex = "/^@.([0-9]|1[0-5])/";
    return replacement.replaceAll(regex, "");
}
```

}

The first two tests run as expected.
The third test (where actually the replacement needs to be done) results in this:

- Expected: There @144are some @16which i want to get rid of!
- Actual: @12There @144are @5some @16which i @15want to @0get rid of!

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you don't surround the regex with `/`. Also, the `.` requires a character between the `@` and the first digit. Finally, the `^` would only match at the start of the string. Thus, the

```
String regex = "/^@.([0-9]|1[0-5])/";
```

should be

```
String regex = "@([0-9]|1[0-5])";
```

Finally, to prevent matching three-digit, four-digit etc sequences, add negative lookahead:

```
String regex = "@([0-9]|1[0-5])(?![0-9])";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@(?:\d|1[0-5])(?!\d)
```

or for java

```
@(?:\\d|1[0-5])(?!\\d)
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `empty string`

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/9

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/10

Answer (score -1):

You can use Regex like this :

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
    String s1 = "@01Test";
    String s2 = "@10Test";
    String s3 = "@16Test";
    String s4 = "@15Test";
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("@(0[0-9]|1[0-5])(?=Test)", ""));
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("@(0[0-9]|1[0-5])(?=Test)", ""));
    System.out.println(s3.replaceAll("@(0[0-9]|1[0-5])(?=Test)", ""));
    System.out.println(s4.replaceAll("@(0[0-9]|1[0-5])(?=Test)", ""));
}
```

O/P :

```
Test
Test
@16Test
Test
```